# XML ERROR in Style REASON: Missing Tag

Tags: excel, xls

I'm desperate for a resolution to my problem.
I can't open an excel (.xls) file.  Get window with message: Problems came up in the following areas during load: Styles.
When I go to the log file it gives me the following:

XML ERROR in Style
REASON: Missing Tag

Is there any way I can restore this file or at least extract my data from it?

Answer (score 1):

I also just had exactly this same error. I was able to solve it by manually deleting in notepadd++ all the  tags which don't have an ID. See the picture attached.

In my case there were 8 of them all below the "ss:ID="Default"" Style.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few years down the line this is prob irrelevant but try the following (you'll lose your formatting).
Assuming that your formatting tag looks something like this [this is from an Excel-saved Workday-compatible XML but the idea will be roughly the same elsewhere too]:

```
ss:StyleID="s64" // or similar in vein
```

regex replace (use notepad++ if not sure, it's free)

```
ss:StyleID=".*?(?=")"
```

...with nothing.
Then delete your whole `<Styles>...</Styles>` block.

Suggestion, if you're using Excel to save XML files, use XLSX for any workings and then save as XML when finished done. XLSX is a lot smaller and isn't prone to the style error issue.